# Copy & Paste URL Link

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, copy

Does anybody know how to copy the URL of the current page and then "paste" the URL automatically into a href tag like this:

`<a href="--paste it here--">click</a>`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: specify your question! Or take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
<?php echo '<a href="http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'">This page</a>; ?>
```

Altough it is not copy paste but it should get you the current url of the page.

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'>click</a>";
```